# concatenation in array javascript using plus sign

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was trying to concatenate two array using + sign but result i was getting is:first array's last element is concatenated to first element of second array why it is happening is there is any specific reason  I tried

```
var a=[1,2,3]; 
var b=[5,7,8]; 
console.log(a+b);
```

I got result 1,2,35,7,8

Comment: `+` operator concatenates strings, not arrays. Your arrays are converted to strings before concatenation.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items

Answer (score 5):

`+` operator turns arrays into strings, use `Array.prototype.concat` instead.

```
console.log(a.concat(b));
```